# Can't import matplotlib.artist despite it being in \site-packages

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I'm running a deep learning experiment on a temporary PC, but seem to have some path or environment problems. I don't use matplotlib directly in my code but get the following error when trying to import a separate module :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-78e172347b91> in <module>
----> 1 from imageai.Detection import VideoObjectDetection
      2 import os
      3 execution_path = os.getcwd()
      4 detector = VideoObjectDetection()
      5 #  SqueezeNet, ResNet, InceptionV3 and DenseNet.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imageai\Detection\__init__.py in <module>
      6 from imageai.Detection.keras_retinanet.utils.colors import label_color
      7 
----> 8 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      9 import matplotlib.image as pltimage
     10 import numpy as np

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in <module>
   1109 with warnings.catch_warnings():
   1110     warnings.simplefilter("ignore", MatplotlibDeprecationWarning)
-> 1111     rcParamsOrig = RcParams(rcParams.copy())
   1112     rcParamsDefault = RcParams([(key, default) for key, (default, converter) in
   1113                                 defaultParams.items()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    889             val = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
    890             if val is rcsetup._auto_backend_sentinel:
--> 891                 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    892                 plt.switch_backend(rcsetup._auto_backend_sentinel)
    893 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>
     30 from cycler import cycler
     31 import matplotlib
---> 32 import matplotlib.colorbar
     33 import matplotlib.image
     34 from matplotlib import rcsetup, style

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py in <module>
     26 
     27 import matplotlib as mpl
---> 28 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     29 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
     30 import matplotlib.collections as collections

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'artist'
```

I have checked `~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib` and everything seems to be fine. Anyone know what's causing this? I could not find a similar problem here. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling both a previous version and current of matplotlib to no avail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [HERE](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12626)

Comment: This should be fixed by https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12604 and should hence only occur in version 3.0.0 of matplotlib. Any newer or older version should not exibit this error. So probably something went wrong when uninstalling/reinstalling.

Comment: You may have matplotlib installed via both `pip` and `conda` which may have caused the problem. Be sure you `pip uninstall matplotlib` then `conda install --force matplotlib` and you should be good to go.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest Thank you, I read through the fixes and saw the bug. indeed version 3.0.0 was the problem, but also apparently, if your jupyter notebook is open and you uninstall and reinstall a different version of matplotlib, it still wouldn't work. Not sure why though because the import would still point to whatever the installed matplotlib is but oh well. Had to close and reopen the notebook with the new version of matplotlib for it to work.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Thank you for this

Comment: @alec_djinn thanks, this greatly helped and did the trick!